# perl - trying to sort an array of 'hashes' based on values

Tags: arrays, sorting, perl, hash

I'm populating an array with file detail values like this:

```
push(@local_files,{fname=>$bname, fdate=>$lfdate, fsize=>$lfsize});
```

then trying to sort these based on 'fname' descending order as shown in these examples and many others:

```
my @sorted=sort { $b->{'fname'} <=> $a->{'fname'} } \@local_files;

my @sorted=sort { $local_files['fname']{$b} cmp $local_files['fname']{$a} } @local_files;
```

Nothing I've tried has worked to sort this array, this is what I need help with.

But using dumper I can see that values are stored in the array

```
foreach my $whatever(@sorted){
        ## this works to dump contents of whatever
        print Dumper(\$whatever);

}
```

gives me output like this (snippet):

```
 {
              'fdate' => '88.837662037037',
              'fname' => 'Testfile997.txt',
              'fsize' => 4415
            },
            {
              'fdate' => '88.837662037037',
              'fname' => 'Testfile998.txt',
              'fsize' => 4415
            },
```

Eventually I want to be able to sort by any of the 3 values stored, but multiple searches have not been useful.  Any help is appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Good tries, just simple stuff is off: (1) sort `@local_files` (not a reference `\@local_files`) (2) Compare filenames (strings) using lexicographical comparison (`cmp`), not numeric (`<=>`).  So altogether: `my @sorted = sort { $b->{fname} cmp $a->{fname} } @local_files;`  (To sort by `fdate` and `fsize` do use numerical comparison `<=>`).  Reference is [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Equality-Operators)

Comment: [cont'ed since it cut me off at 5min]  A little bummer is that you have to know (whether it's strings or numbers).  Note that the absence of quotes on hash keys, `$b->{fname}`, isn't a typo -- we may leave them out under some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @zdim - this worked.   I don't think I can accept this as answer because it's in a comment.  ?  thanks though!

Comment: "_this worked_"  -- great :)   As for accepting, thank you for asking -- no, one indeed can't accept comments, but you got a nice answer. (It also correctly brought up a possible need to sort by "mixed" strings and a library `Sort::Key`.)  What one accepts is a personal decision but I'm completely comfortable suggesting to accept that.

Comment: yes, that Sort::Key thing is good to know - I did see it in my searching, but I generally avoid installing new things unless they would save a lot of work - in this case no, the solution is pretty efficient

Comment: "_I generally avoid installing new things unless they would save a lot of work_" -- yeah, similar here ... this one (`Sort::Key`) is good to have (and use).  Very efficient too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it the first time. Correct:

```perl
my @sorted = sort { $b->{ fname } cmp $a->{ fname } } @local_files;
```

You had a stray `\`, and you were performing a numerical comparison instead of a string comparison. (I removed the unneeded `'`, but that doesn't matter.)

It can also be done quite nicely with Sort-Key.

```perl
use Sort::Key qw( rskeysort );

my @sorted = rskeysort { $_->{ fname } } @local_files;
```

Note that you will have problems with both of the above if you have `Testfile99` (rather than `Testfile099`) and `Testfile100` (since `9` comes after `1`). Using a natural sort will do the trick.

```perl
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( rnatkeysort );

my @sorted = rnatkeysort { $_->{ fname } } @local_files;
```

---

> I want to be able to sort by any of the 3 values stored

```perl
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( rnatkeysort );

my %sorters = (
   by_fname_desc => sub { rnatkeysort { $_->{ fname } } @_ },
   ...
);

my $order = "by_fname_desc";  # Or whatever

my $sorter = $sorters{ $order }
   or die( "Unknown order `$order`" );

my @sorted = $sorter->( @local_files );
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion is what worked, same as that posted in a comment by zdim, I appreciate the speedy replies!

Comment: Re "*your first suggestion is what worked*", Except it doesn't if your numbers have different lengths, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I'll keep these things in mind.  Right now I will really be sorting on numeric values (age in epoch seconds most importantly) - may or may not need to worry about the numbers in file names.  I just focused on the name values because all my test files have different names, but same sizes and very close ages (within a second max difference)